# 5 most common words in text file python

Tags: python

i have this code to search for the 5 most common words in a text file but i cant use the sort and reverse functions at the end of the program... how would i avoid using them?

```
words = open('romeo.txt').read().lower().split()


uniques = []
for word in words:
  if word not in uniques:
    uniques.append(word)


counts = []
for unique in uniques:
  count = 0              
  for word in words:     
    if word == unique:   
      count += 1         
  counts.append((count, unique))

counts.sort()            
counts.reverse()         

for i in range(min(5, len(counts))):
  count, word = counts[i]
  print('%s %d' % (word, count))
```

Comment: I think when you use sort, you should save the results before reversing it, so the `counts.sort()` doesn't update counts

Comment: Before counting (or sorting), you may want to 'normalize' the words.  Lowercase? De-pluralize? Remove verb endings?

Answer (score 5):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(words)
c.most_common(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sorted()` function and save the results in a variable then reverse it like this:

```
counts = sorted(counts, reverse=True)
```

That line of code will sort the list and reverse it for you and save the results in counts. Then you can use your count as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_name = input('Enter the filename: ')
if len(file_name) < 1: file_name = 'intro.txt'

counts = dict()
try:
    file_handle = open(file_name)
    for line in file_handle:
        words = line.rstrip().split()

# get the frequency of each word
        for word in words:
            counts[word] = counts.get(word, 0) + 1

# get top 5 based on value: store them in a list of tuples
    temp_list = list()
    for (k, v) in counts.items():
        temp_list.append((v, k))

# sort the list now: it will sort based on left value in the tuple (v,k) so v. we want top 5, so reverse
    temp_list = sorted(temp_list, reverse=True)
   
# print the top 5 words
    for (v, k) in temp_list[:5]:
        print(k, v)

except:
    print('Invalid File')
    quit()
```